# Make a batch file find duplicate file names with different extensions, and actions on the results

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch

What I want to do is have a batch file search folders, and subfolders, for matching file names that are ending in `.mp3` and `.wma` and delete or move the `*.wma` duplicates.

Below you'll find what I have come up with until now, I know it is wrong for at least two reasons. I have searched the internet, and tried a number of things, but now I am stuck. Can anyone please help me with this?

```
for /r %%f in "(%userprofile%\my music\* - ?.*)" do del "%%f" /s/p
```

Comment: Why not use a free tool from ashisoft duplicate file finder. http://www.ashisoft.com

Comment: Because it costs $30.00. the free version will not work on the task I want unless I buy it. I would rather learn how to do it, than throw money at it. But thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no windows guru but [forfiles](http://www.computerhope.com/forfiles.htm) is pretty straight forward.
`forfiles /p "%userprofile%\my music\" /s /m *.mp3 /C "cmd /c del @relpath@fname.wma"`

Comment: I appreciate your response Micke. I am not a guru either. I am actually pretty new at writing batch files. I have written a few easy batch files using the basics, but that is all. I have tried your solution, and I think it is much closer to what I need than what I had. However it did not work. I receive an error as follows,        ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '@relpath@fname.wma'        I would appreciate any other ideas you may have. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, I got it to kind of work. I input it as:    FORFILES /P "%USERPROFILE%\MY MUSIC" /S /M *.MP3 /C "CMD /C DEL @FNAME.WMA"  It did not like the "\" behind "my music" or "@relpath" with "@fname" for some reason. It does delete *.wma files that have a duplicate *.mp3 file. However, only the same folder, and not in lateral folders. Any ideas? thank you again for your help.

Comment: Try adding `@PATH\ ` before `@FNAME` instead of `@RELPATH`. You want it to expand to the path and the filename plus your extension (.WMA) so DEL can run. I'm not at a Windows computer right now so unfortunately I cannot try it myself.

Comment: That didn't work, or I typed it incorrectly. It works using @fname by itself, but it only deletes *.WMA files in the current directory where an *.MP3 was found, and not in the rest of the directories.

Answer (score 1):

May I recommend powershell?

```
cd C:\users\Administrator\Desktop\test\


$Afiles = ls *.text
$Bfiles = ls *.txt

$Alist = @()
$Blist = @()

foreach( $A in $Afiles)
{
    $Alist += $A.BaseName
}

foreach( $B in $Bfiles)
{
    $Blist += $B.BaseName
}

foreach($A in $Alist)
{
    if($Blist -contains $a) 
    {
        rm ("$A.text") -WhatIf
    }
}
```

while this may seem a bit more complicated, its much more extensible and reusable IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for brining up that old question, but for anyone who stumbles here in the future, check this out, this works in a batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%A IN (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z) DO (DIR /B /S /A-D %%A:\>>FILELIST.TXT) 2>NUL
```

http://www.ehow.com/how_6926969_remove-files-xp-operating-system.html

Answer (score 0):

this worked really great for what i needed

```
forfiles /P C:\Projects\QualityPush\ /S /M  first.txt /C "cmd /c echo @path"
forfiles /P C:\Projects\QualityPush\ /S /M  second.txt /C "cmd /c echo @path"
```

This will give you the path to each file for any matches in sub dirs and keeps them collated together